# More elegant way to put translations inside tags values

Tags: grails, view

A little trivial question....

What is the more elegant way to put translations inside a view inside other tags?

Mode 1:

```
<g:submitButton name="signup" value="${g.message(code:'signUp')}"/>
```

or Mode 2:

```
<submitButton id="signInOrUp" name="signInOrUp" value="<g:message code='signUp' />"/>
```

Thank you.

Comment: personally - the first one. generally - whatever pleases your eye :)

Comment: I would also say the first one, it's also what the core Grails developers use in their documentation etc.

Comment: Mode 1. It's a bit strange path a tag in expression in another tag.